# Access to an undefined property Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model:: larastan

Tags: php, phpstan

i´m trying solve this problem in laravel with `larastan`

```
Access to an undefined property                                           
         Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::$bloqueante
```

I´m doing in my class:

```
/**
 * @property int $id
 * @property bool $bloqueante
 * @property string $mensajeError
 * \Illuminate\Support\Collection<Validacion> $validacion
 */
```

This properties it´s my errors. The code that return this message it´s, for example:

```
$this->validacion = Validacion::where('tipoFicheroControl_id' .....)->first()
.................
$mensaje = json_encode([
                "tipo" => ($this->validacion->bloqueante == 1) ? 'Error' : 'Warning',
```

I changed my logic in variable $this->validacion. Before this variable it´s defined in locally. Now it´s defined in class with protected.

other similar error, i can solve using: `* \Illuminate\Support\Collection<Validacion> $validacion`

In my model i have defined:

```
/**
 * App\Models\Validacion
 *
 * @property string $clasePHP
 * @property string $mensajeError
 * @property bool $bloqueante
 * @property string $parametrosClase
 * @property bool $habilitada
 * @property EstructuraFichero $columna
 */
```

and i have `fillable` array. But in this class always return this message.

Sorry for my bad english, and i hope that anybody can help me.

Comment: Best to ask this in Larastan's GitHub issues.